# m2crypto threading usage

Tags: m2crypto

the documentation is somehow sparse. I intend to use m2crypto in a webserver and it seems m2crypto.threading.init() shall be used.

Shall my python function called upon web request be something as:

```
def do_something():
   M2Crypto.threading.init()
   sign something with m2crypto
   M2Crypto.threading.cleanup()
   return httpresponse
```

or something else?
Any web reference on this threading usage?

Thanks
Nenad

Answer (score 0):

What is your deployment model? If you use something like mod_wsgi where you have separate processes, you need to set up threading just once during the lifetime of the python process.